# 8GB memory stick not recognised on Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3V rev.2

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard

I have currently running on my Win7 64-bit i3 system 2x 2GB 1333 sticks running well. I need to upgrade to 8 GB either 1600 or 1333 but have failed to get the system to boot up at all. when i replace them with the 2 x 2GB things go back to normal. Is there something I need to do to get the Mobo to reconise these new 8 gb sticks?

Comment: Is your 8GB RAM listed on the `Memory Support List` on the CPU/Memory Support and Download page?http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4151#memory%20support%20list

Comment: @Suresh - Does your motherboard support a 8GB configuration?  Have you configured each of the 4 sticks work?  Are all 4 sticks the same speed, mixing and matching the speed, is likely a possible reason its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Corsair 1x8gb 1600 or 2x4gb 1600 or to max it out 2x8gb 1600. Of the 8gb sticks listed on the [Memory Support List](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4151#memory%20support%20list) I would only use the Corsair brand as I feel the others are inferior in quality (totally opinion though). If the sticks you got are on the list running at 1600 and didn't work you can try to go into your bios and reduce the speed to 1333 and see if they work. If they do I would return them and get one of the ones I suggested. Then try those. If the Corsairs don't work at 1600  then I would once again return those and get Corsair running at 1333 until you can get your slots to run at the correct speed. Which is a different issue. Ex. messed settings in your Bios.